# How to check if List<obj> is null?

Tags: java, list

I have a list that takes a list from my server. this list will hold whatever the server finds at the database ex.

```
List<OBJ> lstObj = new Arraylist<OBJ>;

Service.getOBJ(new AsyncCallback<List<OBJ>>(){
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        caught.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<OBJ> result) {
        //line to check if result is null
    }
});
```

I have tried

```
if(result==null){
}
```

and also tried

```
if(result.isempty(){
}
```

but it didnt work. the list will be null if the server doesnt find any record from the database. all i need to do is check if the list is empty.

Answer (score 21):

Checking if the list is *empty* and checking if `result` is null are very different things.

```
if (result == null)
```

will see if the value of `result` is a null reference, i.e. it doesn't refer to *any* list.

```
if (result.isEmpty())
```

will see if the value of `result` is a reference to an empty list... the *list* exists, it just doesn't have any elements.

And of course, in cases where you don't know if `result` could be null *or* empty, just use:

```
if (result == null || result.isEmpty())
```

Comment: @Keyser: Yup - I couldn't remember for sure, and was just looking it up.

Comment: Never bad to remember [isEmpty](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty(java.util.Collection)) from [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections) that already performs null check.

Answer (score 6):

Check number of elements in resulting List:

```
if (0==result.size()) {

    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will do like this:

```
if (test != null && !test.isEmpty()) { }
```

This will check for both null and empty, meaning if it is not null and not empty do your processing.

Answer (score 2):

You're obviously new at this programming thing if you didn't already validate your server, so I'm trying to aim a guess at what might be going on with your server.  Depending on what your "" objects are, you could have valid objects that represent data that is meaningless in different ways.  For example, you may have String objects with various kinds of white space.

This happens a lot on servers that provide answers using PHP and JSP, where pages are assembled using various include mechanisms and there is white space between them.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do for your code. If you want a negation logic just modify accordingly.
As also suggested by someone CollectionUtils provide just utility methods which removes such null check LOC.

```
result == null || result.isEmpty()
```

Hope this helps!